Обведение объекта на фотографии по контуру
Я хочу разработать функционал обведения объектов прямыми линиями по контуру, как на примере на картинке. То есть я выделяю дорогу линиями по контуру. При замыкании контура, он закрашивается, объект остается обведенным, а мы выходим из режима рисования. Подскажите как разработать такое на JS? Какие библиотеки использовать (желательно совместимые с React 18) ?




самое простое это создать поверх картинки svg холст с указанными точками и закрашивать область по нужному вам паттерну. Библиотеки тут особо и не нужны, всё решается средствами самого JS. Но чтобы добиться именно такого результата как на фото, понадобиться немного подключить математику для просчёта наклона, думаю в качестве обучения хватит и без наклона

@MoloF А не canvas тут нужно использовать? Можешь примеры покидать подобных решений, что ты описал?

@DANIELE YO можно и canvas, дело вкуса и ТЗ. В данном случае они взаимозаменяемы.
